# phpbb3 database index too long

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpbb

I've got a problema when i want to install phpbb 3.1.3

```
Index name 'phpbb_acl_options_auth_option' on table 'phpbb_acl_options' is too long. The maximum is 30 characters.
```

Somebody know a solution ?

 Thanks!

Comment: As the error says.. Change the table prefix to something shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> As the error says.. Change the table prefix to something shorter

Problem was that phpbb make and index with `tableprefix` + `table column` which was to long, i had `phpbb_` so i changed the prefix in one shorter `p_` and now it's works.